# How write a .bin file to USB drive under Linux

Tags: linux, usb

How do I write a `.bin`-file to a USB drive on linux? 
The `.bin`-file contains a bootable drive.

How can I achieve this under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the DD command to restore the .bin file to the drive.

be really careful, DD has been nicknamed disk destroyer.

Make sure the device isn't mounted, and then run this command:

```
dd if=/path/to/image.bin of=/dev/sdx
```

you can use

```
fdisk -l
```

to figure out what your usb drive is named.

Comment: Nope, `dd` not works. After using ImageUSB on Windows it gives me a pendrive with ext3 filesystem on it, but now, after `dd` the GParted does not recognizes any FS on the drive.

Comment: @garethTheRed: nope, the file path is correct, does not contain any special character, and the file also correct.

Comment: @NagyVilmos - the `file` command tells you the file type.  If you run it against an disk image it can tell you what is in it.  For example, I ran it against an old image file I found, I get `ks.img: DOS floppy 1440k, DOS/MBR hard disk boot sector` so it gives me an idea of what the file is.  If it came back with something odd, then the file could be corrupt or of an incorrect type for booting.

Comment: @garethTheRed: looks like this:   `image_3_0.bin: dBase IV DBT of e.DBF, blocks size 6750305, next free block index 7143529, 1st item "\3721\300\216\330\216\320\274"`

Comment: That says `dBase IV DBT of e.DBF`.  It doesn't look like a bootable image to me!

Comment: @garethTheRed: I'm sure as hell, that that is a bootable image. I asked for my friends notebook, and wrote that file to an USB on Windows with ImageUSB, and works fine...

Comment: How was the file created? If you used ImageUSB to create it and then to restore it then maybe it's a proprietary format. Also, try the `file` command again, but with the `-k` option this time.  See what it tells you.